# Azure Data Factory V2 Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset : 'TableName' cannot be null

Tags: azure-data-factory

I use following powershell command to create a dataset. This is dataset connects to Azure SQL DB. I will call the stored proc on pipeline based on this dataset connection. However, I got error message "TableName' cannot be null".

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset -DataFactoryName DFName1 -DefinitionFile dataset1.json -Name dataset1 -ResourceGroupName rg1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check whether you are using the latest powershell. You could use Update-Module -Name AzureRm.DataFactoryV2 to update your module. As my understanding, the lasted SDK should make table name as optional.
2. If #1 doesn't resolve your problem, you could just put a dummy table name into your tableName field. For example, tableName: "dummy". If you are using query or stored procedure in your copy source, tableName in dataset will be ignored. 
   But if you are using this dataset as sink and invoke write storedprocedure, tableName field is required, which is the parameter name of your table type.